# Deep learning vm with TPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform

please I need help setting up a **deep learning vm** (dlvm) with **TPU**, I've created the dlvm and a TPU node in the same zone, now when I access **jupyter notebook** it didn't use the TPU node but only the vm configuration (CPU and Ram). I was looking for an option to link the vm with TPU but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`--tpu-only` flag](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/ctpu-reference#:%7E:text=tpu-only):

> Allocate a Cloud TPU only; use this only if you already have a VM available.

Afterwards, when you run your training, specify your TPU and it will be used.

[Example](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quickstart#train_the_model_on):

```
python3 mnist_main.py \
  --tpu=$TPU_NAME \
  --model_dir=$MODEL_DIR \
  --data_dir=$DATA_DIR \
  --train_epochs=10 \
  --distribution_strategy=tpu \
  --download
```

Answer (score -1):

To set up a Deep Learning Virtual Machine (DLVM) with a TPU (Tensor Processing Unit) and ensure that your Jupyter Notebook uses the TPU, you need to configure the environment properly. Here are the steps you should follow:

**1. Create a VM with TPU:**

Ensure that you have created both the DLVM and the TPU node in the same Google Cloud Zone.

**2. Install Necessary Libraries:**

SSH into your DLVM, and make sure you have the necessary libraries installed, such as TensorFlow with TPU support. You can install it using pip:
python code
pip install tensorflow

**3. Initialize TPU Environment:**

You need to specify the TPU name when initializing the TPU environment in your Python code. This links your VM to the TPU node. Here's an example of how you can do this in a Jupyter Notebook:

python code
import tensorflow as tf

## Set the TPU name (replace 'your-tpu-name' with your actual TPU node name)

tpu_name = 'your-tpu-name'

## Create a TPU ClusterResolver

resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://' + tpu_name)

## Connect to the TPU

tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)

## Initialize TPU devices

tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)

## Check if you have connected to the TPU

print("All devices: ", tf.config.list_logical_devices('TPU'))
Make sure to replace 'your-tpu-name' with the actual name of your TPU node.

**4. Run Your Code on TPU:**

Now, when you run your deep learning code in the Jupyter Notebook, it should use the TPU for acceleration. TensorFlow will automatically distribute the computation to the TPU. Make sure your model and training code are compatible with TPUs for optimal performance.

**5. Check TPU Usage:**

You can monitor TPU usage and performance by using tools like tpuvm or checking the Google Cloud Console. This will help you verify that the TPU is indeed being utilized.

**6. Save Your Work:**

Always save your work in your Jupyter Notebook or scripts. TPU nodes may have variable availability, and you don't want to lose your work if the TPU node is preempted.
Remember that TPUs are specialized hardware accelerators, and not all machine learning tasks benefit equally from them. Be sure to optimize your deep learning models and data pipelines for TPU usage to achieve the best performance.